# How to get the number of customer invoices line?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need a way to get all customer invoices line at an open state

[image]

Comment: Where do you want that: In a list view or anywhere at code?

Comment: I need to know how to get the total, and then I will use it in kanban view  @CZoellner

Answer (score 0):

If you need this value in dashboard then add computed field in dashboard model and calculate all open invoices there and add that in dashboard

Comment: Look at my comment below, but the result always 0

Comment: Thats not possible stop debugger and check why it is showing 0 it have to  give values

Answer (score 0):

```
#You first need to get the open invoices
open_invoices = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('state','=','open')]) 
#then get invoice lines
invoice_lines = open_invoices.mapped('line_ids')
```